# Уравнение на С

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, подскажите как можно решить данное уравнение на С, вот самое уравнение, а вот что я написала, вроде все правильно а не работает( Заранее спасибо!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double rezult,c,alterbol,x;
 puts(" Rabota 1 ");
 puts("============================================");
       alterbol=3*pow(x,2)+15*pow(x,3)+25*pow(x,8);
       c=fabs(pow(x,10))+log(199);
      rezult=alterbol/c;
  printf("\a\n Answer:  rezult=%lf, Press any key...", rezult);
  getch( );
```

[image]

Comment: Это не уравнение, это функция. Ее не решают, а вычисляют ее значение, путем замены переменных входными параметрами (значениями).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная x не инициализирована.

Comment: А как ее инициализировать, программа по сути правильно написано. Только как с Х разобраться, тут же в уравнении Х как переменная, и число ей присвоить нельзя(

Comment: Прочтите х с клавиатуры, Вам поможет scanf:  

    x= scanf("%f");

Comment: Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'x' is being used without being initialized. 

Вот что выдает ...

Comment: Вам все правильно он говорит, Вы пытаетесь сделать что-то с Х, но чему он равен?  
Вы его объявили, но ничего не присвоили в значение.

Comment: А что ему присвоить в значении если Х это переменная квадратного уравнения которое находиться в числителе ?

Comment: Ой. Я понял Вас.  
С сам по себе решить такую задачу не сможет. Вы должны сами составить алгоритм решения.  
Если вопрос сводится к тому «как решить уравнение», то задайте его на форуме Математика.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, теперь поняла, просто сделаю ввод значения с клавиатуры :)

Comment: /Мимо проходил/

    scanf("%f",&x);